# Using stddev in Mysql across columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table MYsql table.

```
name, t1 , t2 , t3.
```

there many names, and their scores.

Show would calculate the standard deviation of t1,t2,t3

Tried Select name, stddev(t1,t2,t3), it didnt work.

**This works:**

```
SELECT
  NAME, STDDEV_SAMP(t)   STD
FROM
( SELECT NAME, t1 AS t FROM test._copy
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT NAME, t2 AS t FROM  test._copy
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NAME, t3 AS t FROM  test._copy
) t
GROUP BY  NAME
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STDEV() is an aggregation function.  It takes values from many rows and yields a single result.

```
SELECT
  name,
  STDEV(t1)   standard_deviation_of_t1,
  STDEV(t2)   standard_deviation_of_t2,
  STDEV(t3)   standard_deviation_of_t3
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  name

-- This will give meaningful results if there are several records for the
-- same name.
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't take values from several fields.  Just several rows, to do that you need to re-work your data to have all the values in a single column...

```
SELECT
  name,
  STDEV(t)   standard_deviation_of_all_t_values,
FROM
(
  SELECT name, t1 AS t FROM yourTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT name, t2 AS t FROM yourTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT name, t3 as t FROM yourTable
)
  AS data
GROUP BY
  name
```

**EDIT**

Another option, instead of `UNION ALL` could be...

```
SELECT
  name,
  STDEV(CASE map.field_id WHEN 1 THEN t1 WHEN 2 THEN t2 ELSE t3 END)
FROM
  your_table
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT 1 as field_id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) AS map
GROUP BY
  name
```

Comment: +1 Couldn't get my one working in MySQL. Doesn't seem to allow reference to outer columns in derived tables as far as I can see.

Comment: @Merlin - I've posted an alternative.  But what do you mean by `it works but for edits`?

Comment: (
  SELECT name, t1 AS t FROM yourTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT name, t2 AS t FROM yourTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT name, t3 as t FROM yourTable
) need a "t" to reference table.

Comment: How would use the above with "update statement", I know 'insert', cant figure out.

Comment: What table are you trying to update?  What field?  How does that table/field relate to the query described above?  It may be advisable to create a new question, linking to this one, with the extra details needed for your new question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `GROUP BY name` at the end.