# AVG and STD in MySQL using field values of the same row

Tags: mysql, sql, std, average

I know how to use avg() and std() functions in MySQL to calculate averages or standard deviations from a query or query with group by

```
select avg(amount) from table
select mykey,std(amount) from table group by key
```

My question is, can I use those functions when the set of values are in different columns of a row?

```
mykey value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 myavg mystd
1        5.0    3.0    4.0    5.0    3.0
```

myavg as the average of value1,value2,value3,value4 and value5  (in the example (5+3+4+5+3)/5 = 4)
stdmykey as the standard deviation of value1,value2,value3,value4 and value5

some kind of...

```
update table set
   myavg = avg(value1,value2,value3,value4,value5),
   mystd = std(value1,value2,value3,value4,value5)
```

Comment: I'm guessing, but can you do AVG(value1 +value2 + value3 + value4 + value5); ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419692/using-stddev-in-mysql-across-columns maybe helps

Answer (score 1):

```
update table set
   myavg = (value1+value2+value3+value4+value5)/5,
   mystd = ...
```

Comment: Yes, the avg is easy to calculate, but I was looking for a way to use avg and std with a list of values